Best practice for designing technical forms and reports
I am trying to figure out the best practices for designing forms, especially the engineering and technical forms. I have a lot of inspection reports and engineering forms such as the provided example which contains various sections, some of which must be repeated in several pages (such as the "document number", "revision number", and "signature" sections in the provided example and some of them will span over several pages such as the "Report and remarks" which may need to be written in several pages. I also have documents with several layouts which would be nice if I could produce them in a single Latex document.
I have seen solutions using the "background" and "Tikz" packages. But I think it is better to check with the experts before making hundreds of forms and then figuring out a better way.
My question is: what practice do you find the best practice to approach this problem?
To be clear, I don't want the kind of forms that people can enter data in the PDF. I want to design a latex form and compile it to get the final document.
Example form:



Regarding the answers:
Both Fran and MS-SPO provided very good answers. while Fran's answer is more focused on the layout and how to overcome the challenges of having a field spanning over several pages, the MS-SPO's answer focuses on the "process of designing" and approaching versatile problems. Both answers are valuable and I would have chosen both if I could. I am selecting the Fran's answers because of the provided example which will help the future readers and also because they mentioned various packages and their pros and cons and limitations.
Thank you very much for your help.

...and that "final document" is something that will be printed out that individuals complete by writing on it? So, it won't be an electronic completion; that's what I get from your mention of "I don't want the kind of forms that people can enter data in the PDF."

No, I want to be able to fill these forms in latex. Otherwise designing them in latex has no benefits. I wrote that because there are articles in the forum about "editable" PDFs which is unrelated to this question.

So they're not really forms then. You just want a page with boxes, all of which are prefilled with stuff (text, or possibly graphics).

One would also assume that the document layout (the boxes, or form) are similar across pages. That is, page 1 looks the same as page 2, and so on. Sure, they may differ from another form, but within a specific form all pages have the same layout. Correct?

yes. Generally, they are the same. All of them have the same layout. For example, the section "Report and remarks" may get too large to fit in a page and it continue to the second page.

It seems you need a kind of large page [tag:header-footer], which contain tables, framed boxes, pictures (with or without TikZ). What would be best practice depends on opinion/taste and more concrete requirements. As there are usually several LaTeX packages for the same topic on CTAN, e.g., for page headers and footers, also several solutions can be good practice.

IMHO the best practice could be input any variable text in  the form contents via  macros at the start  (even before of the document preamble) to not get entangled with code of the forms when edit the  template previously made, that is not only annoying, but can easily break the code simply by the edition mistakes.
Even better in another file and include it via \input, to avoid modify the template accidentally.
With respect the boxes, if you do not want really a PDF form, this can be done with tables, minipages o several other ways. Any solution producing the layout that you want is fine, but depending of the complexity of the formularies, it could be better a simple tabular or you may need  some packages for more complex tables (tabularx, tabularray,etc), minipages, or even tikz or tcolorbox.

some of which must be repeated in several pages (such as the "document number", "revision number", and "signature" sections

Then these boxes must be in a header, for instance using the fancyhdr package. There a tons of examples of use in this site.

and some of them will span over several pages such as the "Report and remarks" which may need to be written in several pages.

Expandable boxes in several pages is a bit more complex. The tabular environment is not breakable and some tabular-like environments like longtable are breakable between rows, but not within rows.
However,  at least for one column box, you can make it  breakable  with tcolorbox.
This package have an intimidating huge manual but very flexible, and allow not only that but also things like rasters of boxes that can simulate tabular environments.
I left a MWE using tcolorbox also for a fixed header, but of course, you can mix the approaches and use tcolorbox only for the report, and a simpler and  faster table for the headers.

% ----------- Formulary data ---------------

\def\inspector{Claire Voyant}
\def\aproveitor{Max Approver}
\def\company{Nerdvana Innovations}
\def\address{404 Not Found Lane, Silicon Valley, Bitmore Bytes, CA 94016}
\def\remarks{\lipsum[1-7]}  % longdummy text

% ----------- template ---------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=6cm,headheight=4cm,headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\parindent0pt
\parskip1ex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[poster,raster,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {height=3cm,spacing=3pt,columns=6,rows=3},
boxes = {colback=gray!10,colback=white, sharp corners,boxrule=.4pt},
]
\posterbox{name=A,column=1,span=5}{\centering\bfseries\large\company}
\posterbox[blankest]{name=logo,column=6}{\hfil\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\posterbox{name=B,column=1,span=2,row=2}{\footnotesize Inspector:}
\posterbox[colback=gray!15]{name=C,column=2,span=2,row=2}{\inspector}
\posterbox{name=D,column=1,span=2,row=3}{\footnotesize  Aproved by:}
\posterbox[colback=gray!15]{name=E,column=2,span=2,row=3}{\aproveitor}
\posterbox{name=F,column=4,span=2,between=A and bottom}{\sffamily\footnotesize\address}
\end{tcbposter}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\newtcolorbox[]{bigcell}{
parbox=false,
breakable,
colback=white,
colframe=black,
sharp corners, 
before skip=1pt plus 1pt,
after skip=1pt plus 1pt,
halign= justify,
boxsep= 1ex,
sharp corners, 
boxrule=.4pt
}

\begin{bigcell} {\bfseries Report and remarks:} \par \remarks \end{bigcell}

\end{document}

\begin{celdilla} \lipsum[1][1] \end{celdilla}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,
size=small,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white]
\tcbitem One
\tcbitem Two
\tcbitem Three
\tcbitem Four
\end{tcbitemize}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4, 
size=small,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white]
\tcbitem One
\tcbitem Two
\tcbitem Three
\tcbitem Four
\end{tcbitemize}


\end{document}


In addition to the great specific advice of the other users, I would like to add a few general points due to bad personal experience with forms from banks, the finance authority, travel firms etc.

Please make sure that all input fields are checked during input and during upload if the form can be filled out with a PC. Nobody wants to get a form rejection after upload only due to spaces within an IBAN. If you find errors, report them precisely with example input of the affected field.
If the upload is under your control, make sure to cache the input. The user will get angry if he submits his twenty-page form, an error occurs and he must refill the entire, now again empty form.
Test your forms in the wild, since users are prone to misunderstand ambiguous or unfitting field names. "ID Nr" could be the tax ID, the company ID, the part ID, ... Name could be "John Doe", "Doe, John", "Doe", "John", "Jonny" or "John Alfric Doe". The IBAN could contain spaces or not. The phone number could start with "+49" or "0". Which name parts should be contained in the signature? Give example inputs. What should the user do with a field which is not relevant for him? (writing " -- ", leaving it empty, ...)
Be liberal regarding the form of the entries (Robustness principle).
If possible, ask your form users for improvement ideas. Communication is key.
Display IBAN and phone numbers with spaces automatically during writing them.
Make the form readable. Nobody wants to work with font size 6. In addition, working with a pencil needs sufficient big and long entry fields.
Automatic fill-ins based on previous entry values are great, but the user should be able to overwrite them if your internal logic is erroneous or does not cover all cases.
Consider all use cases. The user will get enerved if he is payed per assignment instead of per hour, but can not fill the fields due to this special case.
Evaluate the forms after the first real-world uses and hold them up-to-date.
Form fields whose values you know in advance (e. g. sex, name, ...) should be automatically filled in advance.
Note that printers may not be able to print without a visible white border. Consider impaired users (Google keyword: accessibility).


Fran already showed a nice implementation. However, this sounds like the request for a systematic approach:

My question is: what practice do you find the best practice to approach this problem?

I suggest to approach this in several steps, e.g.:
1. Forget about the layout as a start
I.e. focus on the content, i.e. introduce a handfull of variables, as Fran did, create a simple document, which lists all the variables content.
Try reproducing your several documents (i.e. the content, the information), just by changing the variables:

if all are the same, changing variables is all you need
if they differ, identify their relationship (i.e. as inheritence)

EXAMPLE: main.tex
Besides defining a few variable its main feature is to define an environment for the Report and Remarks section, for standadization. As you can see, from a developers point of view I was (by intention to show the process) a bit indecisive: where to fill the environment with content, in text (normal LaTeX) or beforehand in a variable?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% ~~~ variables ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\docnr[0]    {12345-67B}
\newcommand\inspctr[0]  {Pink Panther}
\newcommand\sgntr[0]    {Me and the gang}

% ~~~ to standardize your input ~~~~~~~~
\newenvironment{reprem}{Report and Remarks:\\}{\par \hrulefill C'et fini\hrulefill}

% ~~~ you could do this as well: ~~~~~~~~
\def\rr{ Option B: write this into an other variable. This is some test content. So is this
% 
 Or that, or this. See the difference?}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \docnr{}
 \inspctr{}
 
\begin{reprem}  % if you like it in running text
 Option A: write this inside the document. This is some test content. So is this
 
 Or that, or this.
\end{reprem}  
 
 
\begin{reprem}  % if you like it predefined
 \rr{}
\end{reprem}  

 \sgntr{}
\end{document}


Turns out, thinking ahead, the \rr{} route would be more consistent:

fill it in the same place as all the others
"print" it somewhere else.

Ok, time for refactoring, assuming, you can create ALL your documents (contentwise) with whatever layout they have (else, follow the inheritence route, until each object can).
2. Refactoring: separate variables from "printing" them
Ok, let's create two files:
content.tex
% ~~~ variables ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\docnr[0]    {12345-67B}
\newcommand\inspctr[0]  {Pink Panther}
\newcommand\sgntr[0]    {Me and the gang}


% ~~~ REPORT AND REMARKS ~~~~~~~~
\def\rr{ Option B: write this into an other variable. This is some test content. So is this
% 
 Or that, or this. See the difference?}

main2.tex, which just does the "print":
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% ~~~ to standardize your input ~~~~~~~~
\newenvironment{reprem}{Report and Remarks:\\}{\par \hrulefill C'et fini\hrulefill}

\input{content}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \docnr{}
 \inspctr{}
 
\begin{reprem}
 \rr{}
\end{reprem}  

 \sgntr{}
\end{document}

Compile main2 and you'll have:

3. Where to go from here?
Let's assume at this point:

you are satisfied with the way of splitting and handling content (if not: continue changing and refactoring)
you can contentwise create all your documents
then ...

it's time to think in terms of layout. I.e. which variable shall be displayed where (in a box? in a table? in a TikZ-element? etc.)
Continue changing, saving, refactoring until you have a nice set of things you like to work with.
EAXAMPLE: main3.tex shows a very simple and ugly layout approach:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% ~~~ to standardize your input ~~~~~~~~
\newenvironment{reprem}{Report and Remarks:\\}{\bigskip}

\input{content}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \hrule \strut Document Number: \docnr{}
 
 \hrule \strut Inspector: \inspctr{}
 \hrule
 
 \begin{reprem}
  \rr{}
 \end{reprem}  

 \hrule \strut Signature: \sgntr{}
\end{document}


